# How can I calculate the disk space (bytes) used by the documents returned from a mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The scenario is as follows:

- using Mongoose.js in Node.js
- perform a query, like `Model.find().where('something', 'value').exec(callback)`
- you receive an array of documents in the `callback`

**How can I determine the size of those documents on disk?**

Approximations are OK, for me at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by executing your query as a lean query (to get plain JavaScript objects instead of Mongoose document instances) and then dipping down into the BSON library that's part of the native MongoDB driver and calling [`calculateObjectSize`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/bson.html#calculateobjectsize):

```
var bson = mongoose.mongo.BSON;

Model.find().where('something', 'value').lean().exec(function(err, docs) {
    var docsBsonSize = bson.calculateObjectSize(docs));
});
```

It won't give you the size on disk, but it should be a good approximation of the size of BSON docs.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. something to be aware of is that this does not take into account document padding or power of 2 space allocation http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/#usePowerOf2Sizes